# How to remove/replace any line of text with empty string inside a doube quot and leave urls only, with RegEx in .vb.net?

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a list like this

```
"Boring makes sense!"
"http://www.someurl.com/listsolo.php?username=fgt&id=46229&code="
"http://www.someurl2.com/members/listearn.php?username=mprogram&id=465301"
"All is there?"
"http://www.someurl.com/listsolo.php?username=loopa&id=46228&code="
"http://www.someurl3.com/members/mem.php?&mprogram"
"http://someurl4.com/members/mem.php?&loop"
```

I need to remove any kind of text on particular line including double quots with RegEx in vb.net

```
Dim fileName As String = "C:\Downloads\Links.txt"

Dim sr As New StreamReader(fileName)

While Not sr.EndOfStream
   Dim re As String = sr.ReadLine()

   If Not re.StartsWith("http") Then
      re = Regex.Replace(re, "(^[A-Za-z]+)", "", RegexOptions.Multiline)
      lblTest.Text += re.ToString()
   End if
End While

sr.Close()
```

How to do it ...in simple way?

Comment: Maybe just set `re` to an empty string? `re = ""`? I cannot see the logic in the question.

Comment: Not sure to understand ; you seem to want to blank out "non-url" lines and add that to a label text, at the end the label text will have the same thing it has at start ; so just doing nothing would work ?

Comment: I just need to remove any line which is not an url. So in this case i have to need remove
"Boring makes sense!" and
"All is there?" lines

This should be a list of urls

Comment: Remove from where ? your current code shows reading from a `sr` ; probably a StreamReader, so probably a File (that's a lot of probably already) and writing to a label. Some context seem to miss ...

Comment: Yes I load a list with StreamReader and label is just for testing. And what I need is appropriate RegEx to remove text lines

Comment: @user1657904 Again remove from where ? the file ? and why a regex is mandatory ?

Comment: Remove from txt file. Regex is not mandatory . What are you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out :-), this regex

> .[A-Za-z]\w+ .*

remove whole line of text with double quotas. I test regex [here](http://www.regexr.com). Anyway, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq, reading from file, filtering and re-writing back to it :

```
File.WriteAllLines("some path", From line In File.ReadAllLines("some path")
                                Where line.StartsWith("http"))
```

Comment: I got an error message "The process cannot access the file "C:\Downloads\Links.txt"  because it is being used by another process.

Comment: My fault ; ReadLines is lazy so trying to read and write the same file is a problem (could have worked if it was two different files) ; I updated the code to use Read**All**Lines which as the names implies load the file in memory (beware of memory issues for big files) [I also removed the `Not` in the predicate because it's the ones starting with "http" you want to keep not the opposite]

Comment: Changed but I got still the same result :(